# adjusting relivance of index service web search

Tags: asp-classic, indexing-service

I run a website that is using windows indexing service to create a catalog for the search page. I return the top 30 results.

I was asked by a user why a certain page was not returned. The phrase searched was "Papal Blessing Form". That is the exact title of a link that points to a PDF form. I tried having the search return all the matches and the page was not returned. I did however get most every page that had the words "form", "Blessing" & "Papal" on them. I even rebuilt the catalog thinking the page was new and not yet indexed.

How do I modify the index settings so better results are returned?

Mike

Comment: Could you be a little more specific about what you mean by "Windows Indexing Service", eg which of the 3 technologies from the "Note" at the top of https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms690538%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: In windows server 2008, Indexing service: I go to the windows run box, type MMC. In the console, I add in Indexing service snap-in. I then created my catalog and used it as the basis for my search page.

Comment: Thanks, now I know how you're doing it. Have you determined if the PDF is indexed OK?  Try keywords that are unique to it.  Reason being that the issue may not be ranking and relevance but whether it is even in the index.

Answer (score 0):

I have written a [blog post](http://jdlwright.blogspot.ca/2015/03/can-microsoft-indexing-service-results.html) about the Indexing Service which addresses your question and some other points.

Specifically to answer your question:

> -Cannot adjust page ranking.
>
> The ranking system is closed and no API or boosting mechanism exists.
>
> -Indexing PDF documents requires the Adobe IFilter (another link in the chain).

My claim that you cannot adjust weight is based in part and supported by this post by George Cheng: http://objectmix.com/inetserver/291307-how-exactly-does-indexing-service-determine-rank.html

Comment: Well then, if I can not get a good search based upon outdated technology, what do people recommend I use instead of indexing service? I'm asking because I am having trouble finding other programs suitable for the task. One thing to keep in mind is that portions of the site are built with classic ASP, thus requiring an engine that indexes post compiled content as opposed to the files on the hard drive.

Comment: @RCDAWebmaster In my blog post is a link to our product SearchUnit.  It is .NET based so you can install it provided ASP.NET is running on your server (it probably is), and it can index dynamically generated content such as .ASP.  For the search page, it is all JS and AJAX based, so it can run from .ASP pages as well as .HTML even...

Comment: can you please provide a link to the program as google is not taking me it

Comment: @RCDAWebmaster Sure: http://keyoti.com/products/search/dotNetWeb/index.html google splits 'search' and 'unit' automatically, but finds us if you search as one word...